# Retrieving mixed datatypes data from Excel sheet using LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve values from Excel columns which are in mixed format (text, numbers). This how I am initializing the connection string.

```
var connectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text""", fileName);

var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(connectionString);
```

But I am getting zero data when I query for the column values:

```
var xyz = (from model in carDetails
    where (model.MakeDescription == carMakeName && model.YearGroup == carMadeYear) &&
           model.FamilyDescription != null
    select model.FamilyDescription).Distinct().ToList();
```

xyz is always zero, even if there are matching records for `carMakeName` and `carMadeYear` in the `where` clause.

Comment: have you tried the query without any condition means var xyz = (from model in carDetails
    select model.FamilyDescription).Distinct().ToList();  .. issue might be related to datatype

Comment: Yes the issue is related to dataType. In Excel sheet's column , the data is in mixed format . If i remove where clause , data which are in number format are fetched correctly, but those which are in text format returns null , number - correct data , strings - null .